EC2 connected to ECS/ECR not updating with new docker image
I have a docker yaml using github workflows, it pushes up a docker image to the ECR, and then the yaml file automatically updates my ECS service to use that docker image. I am certain that the ECS is being updated correctly because when I push to main on github, I see the old service scale down and the new instance scale up. However, the EC2 which runs my web application, doesn't seem to get updated, it continues to use the old docker image and thus old code, how can I make it so it uses the latest image from the ECS service when I push to main?
When I go and manually reboot the ec2 instance, the new code from main is there but I have to manually reboot which obviously causes downtime, & I don't want to have to manually reboot it. My EC2 instance is running an NPM and vite web application.
Here is my .yaml file for my github workflow
name: Deploy to AWS ECR

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main 

jobs:
  build-and-push:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - name: Checkout code
      uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Get Git commit hash
      id: git_hash
      run: echo "::set-output name=hash::$(git rev-parse --short HEAD)"

    - name: Configure AWS credentials
      uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
      with:
        aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.AWS_KEY_ID }}
        aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
        aws-region: us-east-2

    - name: Login to Amazon ECR
      uses: aws-actions/amazon-ecr-login@v2

    - name: Build, tag, and push image to Amazon ECR
      run: |
        docker build -t dummy/repo:latest .
        docker tag dummy/repo:latest ###.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/dummy/repo:latest
        docker push ###.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/dummy/repo:latest

    - name: Update ECS service
      env:
        AWS_REGION: us-east-2
        CLUSTER_NAME: frontend
        SERVICE_NAME: dummy/repo
      run: |
        aws ecs update-service --cluster $CLUSTER_NAME --service $SERVICE_NAME --force-new-deployment --region $AWS_REGION

Here is the task definition JSON used by the cluster service
{
    "family": "aguacero-frontend",
    "containerDefinitions": [
        {
            "name": "aguacero-frontend",
            "image": "###.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/dummy/repo:latest",
            "cpu": 1024,
            "memory": 512,
            "memoryReservation": 512,
            "portMappings": [
                {
                    "name": "aguacero-frontend-4173-tcp",
                    "containerPort": 4173,
                    "hostPort": 4173,
                    "protocol": "tcp",
                    "appProtocol": "http"
                }
            ],
            "essential": true,
            "environment": [
                {
                    "name": "VITE_HOST_URL",
                    "value": "http://0.0.0.0:8081"
                }
            ],
            "mountPoints": [],
            "volumesFrom": [],
            "logConfiguration": {
                "logDriver": "awslogs",
                "options": {
                    "awslogs-group": "/ecs/aguacero-frontend",
                    "awslogs-create-group": "true",
                    "awslogs-region": "us-east-2",
                    "awslogs-stream-prefix": "ecs"
                }
            },
            "systemControls": []
        }
    ],
    "taskRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::###:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole",
    "executionRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::###:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole",
    "networkMode": "awsvpc",
    "requiresCompatibilities": [
        "EC2"
    ],
    "cpu": "1024",
    "memory": "512",
    "runtimePlatform": {
        "cpuArchitecture": "X86_64",
        "operatingSystemFamily": "LINUX"
    }
}

Pushing to github to build the docker image on the ECR works, as well as the refreshing and updating of the ECS service to use the latest tag from the ECR, but those changes aren't propagated to the EC2 instance that the ECS service is connected to.
